# Public screening rights

Tags: copyright, international

Is there a general worldwide rule for who you approach for [public screening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_and_private_screening) rights if a film has not been released in your country?

Is it some middleman local motion picture association or the copyright holder in the home country of the film?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the rights to screen a film that is protected by copyright law (which is called a "licensing agreement") must be obtained by the owner of the copyright wherever that owner may be found. Often the rights will belong to a movie studio, rather than to the people who are the principal authors of the work.

Some countries (but not the United States) have an "orphan works" exception to this requirement when the owner cannot be located.

The vast majority of countries in the world are part of this copyright law regime, but not every single country has any meaningful enforcement of copyright laws.